# Typescript conditional type differentiate index type vs object

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a typescript validation library [nutso](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nutso). The promise of this lib is that the validation schema is typesafe, meaning the type of the validation object is derived from the original object.

As part of that, the schema is defined as follows:

```
export type Schema<T, R = T> = T extends string ? StringSchema<R> :
                        T extends number ? NumberSchema :
                        T extends Date ? DateSchema :
                        T extends boolean ? BooleanSchema :
                        T extends Array<infer E> ? ArraySchema<E, R> : 
                        T extends [infer U, ...unknown[]] ? TupleSchema<U> :
  // T extends {[key:string], infer V} ? MapSchema<V, R> :  // not working
                        T extends object ? ObjectSchema<T, R> :
                        never;
```

The code is here on [github](https://github.com/sowdri/nutso/blob/master/src/models/schema/Schema.ts)

Basically the schema is chosen based on the type. When switching types, I want to distinguish b/w `{[key:string], infer V}` vs. `T extends object` (or actual types that has types defined statically, but I couldn't find a way to do that.

The indexed types and normal types match both `T extends {[key:string], infer V}` and `T extends object`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,